# How to get out of full screen mode in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Sometimes I accidentally hit a key combination to make the Android AVD emulator go into full screen, and I couldn't figure out how to get out of it without restarting the emulator.  All I could do to escape was Alt+Tab to toggle applications.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Alt+Enter** is the keyboard shortcut to toggle full screen mode in the emulator, just do it again to exit full screen.

FYI, here are some other emulator keyboard shortcuts:

> <kbd>F8</kbd> - toggle cell network on/off
>   <kbd>F9</kbd> - toggle code profiling (when -trace option set)
>   <kbd>Alt+ENTER</kbd> - toggle fullscreen mode
>   <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> - toggle trackball mode
>   <kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd>, <kbd>KEYPAD_7</kbd> - switch to previous layout
>   <kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd>, <kbd>KEYPAD_9</kbd> - switch to next layout
>   <kbd>KEYPAD_MULTIPLY</kbd>  - increase onion alpha
>   <kbd>KEYPAD_DIVIDE</kbd> - decrease onion alpha

Source: http://www.android.encke.net/android-emulator-tutorial.html#Keyboard-Control

Comment: As of 2020 (which to be fair is a good 9 years later) this functionality doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**And For Changing the window size of the Android Emulator**

Append the parameter `-scale ­­<scale factor>` to the Emulator launch parameters. In eclipse, put it in the field "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" within the Run Configuration.

Allowed scale factors are those between 0.1 and 3, although the most common will probably be `-scale 0.5` .

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 3.1.2, move your mouse to top of the screen and the menu should show up. Select View, Exit presentation/distraction-free/fullscreen mode.